# Expo Error getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND assets expo

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

my app is ejected from expo so i have to do expo publish every time i do release build
the method was working perfectly for more than 50 times but suddenly after doing the expo publish when i try to do archive in xcode or generate the release build in android iam getting the following error

In Xcode :

```
Showing All Messages
https://assets/3c851d60ad5ef3f2fe43ebd263490d78
https://assets/1a0e3525dd5df87e77057204129a5e6e
https://assets/2379ae894c2c9f63b852a9f3676c2763
https://assets/5cdf883b18a5651a29a4d1ef276d2457
https://assets/74d124a3caeac2bea111f3ca2f2dd34a
[20:37:23] Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND assets

[20:37:23] Before making a release build, make sure you have run 'expo publish' at least once. Learn more. (​https://expo.fyi/release-builds-with-expo-updates​)
```

In Android :

```
> Task :app:bundleReleaseExpoUpdatesAssets
https://assets/3c851d60ad5ef3f2fe43ebd263490d78
https://assets/1a0e3525dd5df87e77057204129a5e6e
https://assets/2379ae894c2c9f63b852a9f3676c2763
https://assets/5cdf883b18a5651a29a4d1ef276d2457
https://assets/74d124a3caeac2bea111f3ca2f2dd34a
[21:22:20] Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND assets
[21:22:20] Before making a release build, make sure you have run 'expo publish' at least once. Learn more.
```

Even though my expo publish is done and if i try to build archive or apk iam getting the error

I tried clear watchman,
remove node modules,reinstall pod,clear cache.etc
Nothing helps

Comment: https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/15961 can you check this

Answer (score 3):

[Did try this solution using the instructions from the pdf](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/15961#issuecomment-1018448841) but didn't work for me. Spent days looking for solutions but nothing worked for me so I dug into the issue.

My project is using Expo SDK36.

What worked for me is the following solution.

### Requirements

1. Install expo-cli: `npm install expo-cli --save-dev`.

Whenever we make a build using Xcode Archive or Android Gradle `assembleRelease` command, these executes the `expo bundle-assets` command. We are going to replace expo and use the local `expo-cli` in the following steps.

#### iOS Specific solution

1. After installing expo-cli in our project, we need to replace build commands.
2. Go to Xcode > Project Name > Targets > Select you project > Build Phases
3. Under Build Phases > Go to **Expo Bundle Assets** or something similar
   [image]
4. Replace: `expo bundle-assets --platform ios --dest "$dest"` with `npx expo-cli bundle-assets --platform ios --dest "$dest"`
5. Run `npx expo-cli publish --clear`
6. Clean the project and start archiving/building!

#### Android specific solution (for MacOS/Linux)

1. On your project root folder, create a file named `run-exp.sh`.
2. Add these lines inside of `run-exp.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

value=$(cat ~/.expo/PATH)
PATH="$PATH:$value" npx expo-cli "$@"
```

3. Under Project Root Folder, go to `android/app/expo.gradle`
4. Replace this line:

```
commandLine("./node_modules/expokit/detach-scripts/run-exp.sh", "bundle-assets", expoRoot, "--platform", "android", "--dest", assetsDir)
```

with

```
commandLine("./run-exp.sh", "bundle-assets", expoRoot, "--platform", "android", "--dest", assetsDir)
```

5. Run `npx expo-cli publish --clear`
6. On Android studio, clean the project and build the app

#### Android specific solution (for Windows)

1. On your project root folder, create a file named `run-exp.bat`.
2. Add these lines inside of `run-exp.bat`:

```
SET /P STOREDPATH=<"%USERPROFILE%\.expo\PATH"
SET PATH="\"%PATH%;%STOREDPATH%\""
npx expo-cli %*
```

3. Under Project Root Folder, go to `android/app/expo.gradle`
4. Replace this line:

```
commandLine("cmd", "/c", ".\\node_modules\\expokit\\detach-scripts\\run-exp.bat", "bundle-assets", expoRoot, "--platform", "android", "--dest", assetsDir)
```

with

```
commandLine("cmd", "/c", ".\\run-exp.bat", "bundle-assets", expoRoot, "--platform", "android", "--dest", assetsDir)
```

5. Run `npx expo-cli publish --clear`
6. On Android studio, clean the project and build the app

Comment: In Linux, the run-exp.sh might need execution permission: `chmod +x run-exp.sh`

Comment: This solution should be accepted, it's a hack, yes, but it's a great workaround for whoever is not ready to fix this the proper way (upgrading all the things!).